# Microsoft Hosted Agent - Build Failing

Tags: azure-devops

We were trying to build a pipeline using MS Hosted agent with vmImage (vs2017-win2016) for a .net application, but build id is failing with following errors..Any ideas?

> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3672056Z ##[error]Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlertDataLayer\HPAlertDataLayer.cs(17,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3673605Z HPAlertDataLayer.cs(17,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlertDataLayer\HPAlertDataLayer.csproj]
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3676838Z ##[error]Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlertDataLayer\HPAlertDataLayer.cs(28,24): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SQLmanager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3678129Z HPAlertDataLayer.cs(28,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SQLmanager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlertDataLayer\HPAlertDataLayer.csproj]
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3763287Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlertDataLayer\HPAlertDataLayer.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3789756Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlert\HPAlert.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3797456Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Main\HPAlert\Service\HPAlertServices.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3837956Z
> 2020-08-20T08:05:28.3839223Z Build FAILED.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add more details, is it YAML or classic pipeline, which steps are you using, configuration

Comment: It looks that you have an issue with fetching dependencies. Please show your pipeline, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: This issue not yet resolved. Application hosted in On-premises have dependency on DevExpress v14.2. Now when we were building azure pipeline, we were getting the errors above as mentioned. We are following with DevExpress support how to integrate these dependencies in Azure pipelines (Azure DevOps.) since we are using MS Hosted Agent which doesn't allow installing any custom softwares on it.

Comment: @RajatWadhwa, How did you integrate DevExpress dependencies in Azure pipelines?

Comment: I havent done it yet. Can you tell me how can we integrate devexpress dependencies in Azure pipelines. We are using MS Hosted agent & not self hosted. Is that still possible to integrate devexpress dependencies using MS Hosted agent?

Comment: @RajatWadhwa, This has nothing to do with Azure devops, Azure devops is a tool for CI/CD, not for managing dependencies. You should add them by nuget. Then use nuget restore task in the Azure pipeline to restore those dependencies. And how to integrate devexpress dependencies with project is not the previous question in this post. If you want get more details info about it, you need open a new thread about it. This post is more related to the error  `Error CS0246`. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, I will create a new thread to get understanding of managing dependencies via Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft Hosted Agent - Build Failing

According to the error message:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HP' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is a common issue of missing references. The solution to this issue is the reference type you used when adding the reference.

If you are add those references `HP` `SQLmanager` by nuget, you need add a [nuget restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#restore) task to restore those nuget packages.

[image]

If you are reference those dll files directly, you need to add those dll files into the solution/project and submit it to the repo.